# Invalid array display

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, methods, interface

Good day, I have the following assignment:
https://prnt.sc/113pc7j

My problem is the first assignment of the fourth item. I prescribed filling the array with random objects, however, when I want to display this array on the screen, I get different results all the time.
My code:

The interface itself:

```
interface VehicleAndWorkers
{
  String cars();
}
```

First class that implements the interface:

```
   public class TaxiStation implements VehicleAndWorkers{
   TrucksLogistic trucks = new TrucksLogistic();

   public String[] cars = {"KIA", "Hyundai", "Volkswagen", "Lada", "Datsun", "Skoda"};
   int quantCars = 150;
   int workers = 300;

   public String cars() {
   System.out.println("List of models of our taxi fleet: ");
      for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
           System.out.println(cars[i]);
       }
           return null;
   }

   @Override
     public boolean equals(Object obj)
     {
       return trucks.quantTrucks == this.quantCars;
     }

    @Override
      public int hashCode() {
         return Objects.hash(trucks, quantCars);
      }

    @Override
      public String toString() {
           return cars();
       }
     }
```

Second class that implements the interface:

```
public class TrucksLogistic implements VehicleAndWorkers {

String[] trucks = {"Kenworth W900", "Volvo FH16", "Scania R730", "MAN TGS 18.400", "МАЗ 6430", 
"КАМАЗ-5490 НЕО 2"};

int quantTrucks = 40;
int workers = 100;

public String cars()
{
    System.out.println("Our company model list: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < trucks.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(trucks[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("Amount of workers: " + workers);
    System.out.println("Number of trucks: " + quantTrucks);
    System.out.println("The ratio of the number of truck models to the number of trucks: " + 
      Math.round(trucks.length / quantTrucks));

    return null;
}

@Override
public String toString() {

    return cars();
 }
}
```

The class in which I tried to implement working with ArrayList (filling, displaying, etc.):

```
public class InterfaceArray {
 ArrayList<VehicleAndWorkers> array = new ArrayList<>();

public void setArray() {
 int randomLength = (int) Math.floor(random() * 10);

 for (int i = 0; i < randomLength; i++) {
    Random random = new Random();

    int minRandomNum = 1;
    int maxRandomNum = 2;
    int diffRandomNum = maxRandomNum - minRandomNum;
    int randomNum = random.nextInt(diffRandomNum + 1) + minRandomNum;

    if (randomNum == 1) {
        array.add(new TrucksLogistic() {
            @Override
            public String cars() {
                int num = (int) Math.floor(random() * trucks.length);
                quantTrucks = (int) Math.floor(random() * 100);

                Random random = new Random();

                int minWorkers = quantTrucks;
                int maxWorkers = 200;
                int diffWorkers = maxWorkers - minWorkers;

                workers = random.nextInt(diffWorkers + 1);
                workers += minWorkers;

                System.out.println("Number of trucks: " + quantTrucks);
                System.out.println("Amount of workers: " + workers);
                System.out.println("Average number of workers per truck: " + Math.round(workers / 
                   quantTrucks));

                return "Priority truck brand/model: " + trucks[num];
            }
        });
    } else {

        array.add(new TaxiStation() {
            @Override
            public String cars() {
                int num = (int) Math.floor(random() * cars.length);
                quantCars = (int) Math.floor(random() * 100);

                Random random = new Random();

                int minWorkers = quantCars;
                int maxWorkers = 200;
                int diffWorkers = maxWorkers - minWorkers;

                workers = random.nextInt(diffWorkers + 1);
                workers += minWorkers;

                System.out.println("Number of passenger cars: " + quantCars);
                System.out.println("Amount of workers: " + workers);
                System.out.println("Average number of employees per vehicle: " + Math.round(workers / quantCars));

                return "Priority car brand/model:" + cars[num];
            }
        });
    }
 }
}

public void getArray() {
    for (VehicleAndWorkers element : array) {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(element);
        System.out.println("");
    }
   }

   public void sameElements() {
    ////          Set<VehicleAndWorkers> arrayTwo = new LinkedHashSet<>(array);
    ////         for (VehicleAndWorkers element : arrayTwo)
    ////            System.out.println(element + "\n");
    //
    //        for (int element = 0; element < array.size() - 1; element++)
    //        {
    //            for (int i = element + 1; i < array.size(); element++)
    //            {
    //                if (array.get(element).equals(element + 1))
    //                {
    //                    arrayTwo.add(array.get(element + 1));
    //                }
    //            }
    //            array.remove(array.get(element));
    //        }
    //        for (VehicleAndWorkers element : arrayTwo)
    //            System.out.println(element.toString());

    }

    public void sameTypeElements() {
        ArrayList<VehicleAndWorkers> arrayTwo = new ArrayList<>();
     //                for (VehicleAndWorkers element : array)
     //                     {
     //                         if (element)
     //                     }
              }
          }
```

Well, the class in which the methods from the previous class are applied:

```
public class ConsoleInterface {
 void doChoice()
  {
    InterfaceArray interfaceArray = new InterfaceArray();

printOptions();

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int choice = scan.nextInt();

while (choice >= 0 && choice < 5) {
    if (choice == 0) {
        interfaceArray.setArray();
        interfaceArray.getArray();
        printOptions();
        choice = scan.nextInt();
    }
    else if (choice == 1) {
        interfaceArray.setArray();
        printOptions();
        choice = scan.nextInt();
    }
    else if (choice == 2) {
        interfaceArray.sameElements();
        printOptions();
        choice = scan.nextInt();
    }
    else if (choice == 3) {
        interfaceArray.sameTypeElements();
        printOptions();
        choice = scan.nextInt();
    }
    else if (choice == 4) {
        interfaceArray.getArray();
        printOptions();
        choice = scan.nextInt();
    }
 }
}

void printOptions()
{
    System.out.println("Choose an action: \n");
    System.out.println("0 - Fill the array with random elements and display it on the screen. \n");
    System.out.println("1 - Fill the array with random elements. \n");
    System.out.println("2 - Find objects in the array,\n" +
            "      whose functional method returns the same result. \n");
    System.out.println("3 - Split the original array into two arrays, \n" +
                    "      which will store the same type of elements. \n");
    System.out.println("4 - Display the array(-s) to the screen.\n");
    System.out.println("Any key - Exit the application.\n");
 }
}
```

An example of how the program works:

1. I fill the array and immediately output it to the console: https://prnt.sc/113qmkr
2. I get the result:
   https://prnt.sc/113qurt
   https://prnt.sc/113qvaq
3. I try again to display all the objects in the array: https://prnt.sc/113qvz4
4. And... I get completely different results:
   https://prnt.sc/113qwhx
   https://prnt.sc/113qwps

Moreover, as you may have noticed, the length of the array is preserved, but the objects themselves are already different.
Honestly, I don't know what the problem might be, the teacher at the university also threw up his hands, so I will be glad to any criticism, comments and suggestions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you choose choice 0 or 1, you immediately randomize the array again.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of assignments/code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: *"filling the array with **random** objects"* + *"I get different results all the time"* --- Yay! The randomness is working!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is very much code for a Stack Overflow question. Might it be possible that instead you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please?

Comment: @NomadMaker, Yes, but when I press 4, I just have to call the getArray method, which is designed to display an already filled array (the array that we filled when we pressed 0 or 1).

Comment: @Andreas, Read carefully, please. The array should be randomly filled, but when you click on the number 4, the array that we just filled should be displayed. Not a new random one.